# Will Hadoop support multiple threads in local mode?

Tags: multithreading, hadoop, local

When running multiple threads in Hadoop in parallel, some jobs fail randomly. Also there are exceptions like `ChecksumException` and `SaxParserException` (Premature end of file).

Tried many ways to fix these but couldn't find a way around. This seems to be an issue with Hadoop and running multiple parallel threads.

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using threads in the map/reduce tasks?

Comment: And why do you need multiple Threads in a task? You should reread MapReduce and how it is parallized.

Comment: I am trying to run nutch crawler in hadoop local mode. Then for each host trying to maintain separate queues(threads) in which multiple hadoop jobs will run.